# even odd метод css для input не работает

Tags: html, css, css3, события, css-animation

У меня есть таблица перекрашенный методом even, odd в css:
[image: Таблица стилизированный методом even, odd]

Так же в этой таблице есть input, на который задан такой же метод. Но по фото видно, что этот метод не отрабатывает. Как видно на картинке ниже:

[image: Графа input]

Пробовал по отдельности писать, и так же в один класс задать, но не помогает. Может кто то знает решение этой проблемы?

```
.tbody_1 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F4F8FC;
}

.tbody_1 tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
}




.tbody_1 tr, .input_blocks:nth-child(even) {
    height: 38px;
    width: 35px;
    border: 1px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F4F8FC;
}

.tbody_1 tr, .input_blocks:nth-child(odd) {
    height: 38px;
    width: 35px;
    border: 1px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
}
```

Comment: А где HTML? Впрочем и так понятно, что у вас неправильный селектор. Во-первых, лишняя запятая. Во-вторых, even/odd должен быть у tr, а не у input-а.

Comment: запятая появилась в ходе хоть как то вывести input. Ваше решение с tr:nth-child мне помогло. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был моментально решён пользователем [Алексей Тен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten). Проблема заключалась в том что метод nth-child должен следовать сразу после tr:nth-child(even) .input_blocks

[image: Таблица с решением]